# PrimeFaces Media component resize on action

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces Media component to display video preview in a dialog. To achieve this I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>PrimeFaces Test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <p:commandButton value="Modal" type="button" onclick="PF('previewDlg').show();" />

        <p:dialog id="previewDlg"
                  widgetVar="previewDlg"
                  styleClass="overlayWindow"
                  modal="true"
                  resizable="false"
                  closeOnEscape="true"
                  position="bottom center">

            <h:form id="preview">
                <h:panelGrid
                        width="100%"
                        columns="1"
                        cellpadding="0"
                        cellspacing="0"
                        border="0">

                    <p:media id="showPreviewVideo"
                             height="250"
                             styleClass="picturePreview ui-widget"
                             value="#{testView.previewURL}"
                             player="quicktime">
                    </p:media>

                    <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center">
                        <p:commandButton id="previewCancelBtn"
                                         value="Cancel"
                                         immediate="true"
                                         styleClass="buttonCancel"
                                         oncomplete="PF('previewDlg').hide();"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

It displayes modal dialog and the video is shown inside. However, for Internet Explorer I found out a bug - each time I click on the video the dialog is getting smaller. It works correct on Chrome.

I am using:

- Primefaces 6.2.6
- IE 11

Am I missing something or seems to be a bug in PrimeFaces control?

Comment: Hi, before going into it being a bug or not in PrimeFaces, lets go into the 'bugs' in your question. 1:You fail to state PF version info, so trying to replicate will already be a wild attempt. 2: You fail to state IE version info (IE6?, tried different ones?)  3: You fail to make an [mcve] so there might be code that is not visible that influences things (like meta tags related to backwards compatibility or css). 4) You tags things wrongly (how do you **know** it is related to javascript?5) IE is buggy, period and it only happens in IE, you did not add that tag. Please improve

Comment: I fixed the question. As soon as I have minimal example I will change the code as well

Comment: Its possible its a bug.  Can you reproduce it using PrimeFaces Test with a minimal reproducible example: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test  If the answer is yes then report it to the GitHub Issues page attaching your PrimeFaces Test project to help developers debug it.

Comment: I updated the question with full xhtml page which is required to reproduce the bug.